# Getting "Operation aborted " when using SaveAS method to save the mail item from outlook in c#

Tags: c#, outlook

```
public void AccessOutlook()
{
  Application oOutlook;
  NameSpace oNs;
  MAPIFolder oFldr;
  try
  {
    oOutlook = new Application();
    oNs = oOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI");
    oFldr = oNs.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
    string str = "Total Mail(s) in Inbox:" + oFldr.Items.Count;
    string str2 = "Total Unread items = " + oFldr.UnReadItemCount;
    foreach (var oMessage in oFldr.Items)
    {
      MailItem mitem = null;
      try
      {
        if (oMessage != null)
        {
          mitem = (MailItem)oMessage;
          String savepath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + @"\" + "Sridhar.html";
          mitem.BodyFormat = OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;
          mitem.SaveAs(savepath, OlSaveAsType.olHTML);
        }
      }
      catch (System.Exception ex)
      {
      }
      if (mitem != null)
      {
        string str3 = mitem.Subject;
      }
    }
  }
  catch (System.Exception ex)
  {
  }
  finally
  {
    GC.Collect();
    oFldr = null;
    oNs = null;
    oOutlook = null;
  }
}
```

Here I want to convert mail item into PDF, hence in first step I'm trying to get mail item based on subject line and saving it in any outlook supported file formats. But I'm not able to do. Can anyone help with this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Never create empty catch blocks.  That is a really great way to introduce bugs.  Have you stepped through your code to make sure it's really going where you think it's going?

Comment: everything is looks fine, i'm able to read content from all mail items but not able to save them, i'm using  mitem.SaveAs(savepath, OlSaveAsType.olHTML) to save it

Comment: @rory.ap: It's a good tip, but never say never. Empty catch blocks do not introduce bugs, they hide problems (the _problem_ can, if never spotted, result in unexpected behavior). There are use cases for empty catch blocks, e.g. when using failover systems (connect to main server and return. If error (empty catch), connect to backup server). I'm not arguing that it's good practice, but there are use cases.

Comment: @Flater -- We're arguing semantics.  What I call "bug" you call "problem" or "unexpected behavior".  At any rate, even putting a comment in the catch block shows that you the developer have given it some thought other than just leaving it empty, possibly by mistake.

Comment: @rory.ap `Never create empty catch blocks. That is a really great way to introduce bugs.` Empty catch blocks do not inherently introduce bugs. Comments in empty catch blocks do not inherently prevent the introduction of bugs. This is not semantics.

Comment: @Flater -- Comments in catch blocks show future developers that you have given it some thought, compared to empty catch blocks which are ambiguous.  It may be the case that you meant to put something in the catch block and got distracted momentarily, then forgot about it.  My habit is to always immediately put a `throw new NotImplementedException(); /* TODO: finish this. */` in there so it will be obvious when the code runs and hits that catch block, and it will also show up on the task list because of the `TODO`.  Why would you argue against a safer approach?

Comment: @rory.ap `Empty catch blocks do not introduce bugs` `I'm not arguing that it's good practice, but there are use cases` At no point have I argued against safe approaches. I have argued against your statement that empty catch blocks **introduce bugs**.

Comment: @Flater -- You're being pedantic, and it's irritating.  I didn't say "empty catch blocks introduce bugs" I said "Never create empty catch blocks. That is a really great way to introduce bugs."  I've already amply explained why in our polemic.

Comment: I just kept the try catch to abserve the stack trace to understand the issue. Here the issue is not able to save mail item in local folder, it is giving "Operation Obrted" message at mitem.SaveAS() line. Can anyone help me with that please

Comment: Why do you set the BodyFormat property? Do you get the same error if you use formats other than olHTML?